# Factoriality of complete intersections

Tags: reference-request, ag.algebraic-geometry, complete-intersection

Let $X\subset\mathbb{P} _{\mathbb{C}}^N$ be a normal complete intersection.

$X$ is called factorial if every Weil divisor on it is Cartier;
equivalently if all local rings $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ are unique 
factorization domains.

Is it true that if
$$ \dim(\mathrm{sing}(X))<\dim(X)-3, $$
then 
$X$ is factorial?

Thanks.

Comment: I think for local rings this was Samuel's Conjecture, proved by Grothendieck in SGA 2.

Comment: Post this as an answer then.

Comment: here is a reference (to a reference):https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381843/how-does-local-cohomology-detect-ufd